# Python & buildout : get path to the egg in the recipe API

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a recipe for buildout which will compile some software, using the standard `./configure`, `make`, `make install`.
The problem is that i don't know how to get the path of the egg directly in the recipe.

Here is a part of my recipe :

```
class ApacheRecipe:
  def __init__(self, buildout, name, options):
    [...]
  def install(self):
    if self.force_install:
      shutil.rmtree(self.install_path)
    if not os.path.exists(self.install_path):
      os.mkdir(self.install_path)
    egg_path = get_current_egg_path() #FIXME: how ?
    os.chdir(egg_path)
    f = os.popen('./configure')
    [...]
```

Comment: Consider using [`zc.recipe.cmmi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.cmmi) if you want to do exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: Even if it's exactly what i'm looking for, it doesn't answer to the question and i may need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... You could have read the source code in the comment I left pointing you towards [`zc.recipe.cmmi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.cmmi) and you would have noted the following in the `Recipe` class in `zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py`

```
class Recipe(object):

    def __init__(self, buildout, name, options):
        self.buildout, self.name, self.options = buildout, name, options
        directory = buildout['buildout']['directory']
        download_cache = buildout['buildout'].get('download-cache')
```

Also consider reading the rest of the code there and see how it should be done, such as using `tempfile` to build temporary modules and such.

Comment: If you are active on this site, can we considere reworking this question ? I was working on another project and I needed an answer to this question. This question is the only one using this subject (checkout `python buildout get path egg` on google), and I think clarifying the subject could be a good idea.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question and link this one with that (by mentioning the link to this page in the question or in its comments)... unless you want a _better_ answer, however the source code in question answers that.